# Open Atrium search always resets the user's current language of site

Tags: search, i18n-l10n, distributions

I've a multilingual site which has 2 languages one is English running at www.example.com/en and another is french running at www.example.com/fr

Now, what oa_search module does is it checks the condition for search and then sends the search keyword to user or node according to the condition.

i.e. www/example.com/search/node/[search_keyword] or
www.example/com/search/user/[search_keyword]

I've found the following code (inside root/profiles/openatrium/modules/apps/oa_search/oa_search.js) responsible for this behaviour:

var path =  Drupal.settings.basePath +  'search' + '/' + (type === 'users' ? 'user' : 'node') + '/' + term;

The issue is every time I search a keyword the search is redirected to 
www.example.com/search/node/[search_keyword] instead of www.example.com/**[language_keyword]**/search/node/[search_keyword]

as a result of which user's language is reset after making a search.

How to solve this problem??